# Conseguir numero de filas que contienen cierto valor, y ese valor ponerlo en otra tabla

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

que tal? Tras cierta busqueda en stack overflow, no pude encontrar la solucion al siguiente problema.

Tengo la siguiente tabla, en la que hay una columna en la que hirian la cantidad de posteos que tiene esa persona a su nombre en otra tabla.

Esta seria la tabla de usuarios.

```
________________________________
| user_id | first_name | posts |
|_________|____________|_______|
| 1       | John       | xxxxx | <-- Ahi iria la cantidad de posts.
|_________|____________|_______|     En este caso 4.
```

Esta seria la tabla de posts

```
_______________________________
| post_id | author_id | title |
|_________|___________|_______|
| 1       | 1         | test1 |
|_________|___________|_______|
| 2       | 1         | test2 |
|_________|___________|_______|
| 3       | 1         | test3 |
|_________|___________|_______|
| 4       | 1         | test4 |
|_________|___________|_______|
```

Author id es un foreign key a la tabla de usuarios donde hace referencia al usuario con id 1 (John).

Si quisiese que el valor de el usuario john en la columna de posts, sea la cantidad de filas que tienen de author_id su id, como haria? Se podria hacer que esta se actualizace automoaticamente? Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.first_name
    COUNT(p.post_id) posts 
FROM usuarios u
    INNER JOIN posts p ON u.user_id=p.author_id
GROUP BY u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id=1;
```

Aquí la combinación de `COUNT` y `GROUP BY` permitirá contar el total de posts del autor y mostrar una sola fila por autor. Las dos tablas son unidas mediante las llaves primarias/foráneas.

`u` y `p` son alias abreviados de tablas. No uso  *as*  para los alias, porque está permitido hacerlo así. A mí al menos me parece más elegante.

El `WHERE` es para filtrar por un autor específico. Si se lo quitas te contará los posts por cada autor.

En cuanto a tu duda sobre si:

> ¿Se podria hacer que esta se actualizace automoaticamente?

No sé a qué te refieres, pero puede que sea tema para otra pregunta, previa investigación de tu parte.

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que necesito en realidad es que no sea una consula. Cuando se agregue una fila a la tabla de posts, se actualize el numero de posts del usuario? es posible tal cosa en sql?

Comment: @TeoVilla todo es posible, pero habría que preguntarse ¿qué es lo más conveniente y lo más fácil de mantener? Por lo general no es buena idea guardar valores calculados en la base de datos, por el hecho de que te obliga a estar escribiendo constantemente en la BD, a establecer una estrategia de actualización/sincronización adecuada, a almacenar datos que ni siquiera sabes si necesitaras ni con que frecuencia. He mencionado al menos tres tareas suplementarias y de todos modos cuando necesites la información tendrás que consultar. Entonces en vez de tanto lío...

Comment: ... ¿por qué mejor no contar los datos en el momento en que se necesiten? Es mucho más fácil y menos costoso para todo el mundo. Y mucho más seguro. Si fallas en tu estrategia de almacenamiento/mantenimiento podrías tener datos erróneos.

Comment: correcto... Necesito que halla una columna con un numero con la cantidad de posts, entonces tendria que hacerlo actualizando cada ves ese numero?

Comment: En mi caso estoy armando una api, donde cuando se consiguen los datos de un usuario y alli tendria que estar la cantidad de posts. Tendria que hacer que cuando se agrega un post ese numero se incremente por 1 y cuando se borra un post este baje en 1. Todo esto en un metodo separado.